# TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 const { member, mentions } = message;

 const tag = `<@${member.id}>`;

 if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ban`)) {
  if (
   member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') ||
   member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')
  ) {
   const target = mentions.user.first();
   if (target) {
    const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
    targetMember.ban();
    message.channel.send(
     `${tag} Cet.te ancien.ne membre a été bannii avec succès !`
    );
   } else {
    message.channel.send(`${tag} Merci de spécifier le membre à bannir.`);
   }
  } else {
   message.channel.send(
    `${tag} Tu n'as pas la permission d'effectuer cette commande.`
   );
  }
 }
});
```

I'm not sure what the error in my code is, any help is appreciated! I would also take any suggestions on how to improve this code in general.

Comment: this is not java, this is javascript. the element on which you try to call the first element isn't defined, in Java it would be null.

Comment: @Stultuske I get the tags wrong all the time, thanks for correcting me! Have a good day :)

Comment: I think you just reversed the order: `mentions.first().user` would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is not a property of `mentions`. Instead use `users`:

```js
mentions.users.first();
```

**[`MessageMentions` docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions)**

---

Also, as a bit of a suggestion, instead of getting the mention as a `User` object, then turning it into a `GuildMember` object, you could just skip straight to the `GuildMember` object.

```js
// instead of:
const target = mentions.users.first();

// use:
const target = mentions.members.first();
```

[`mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) returns a collection of every user that was mentioned in that message. You are taking the first `User` object (first mention).

You are *then* turning that `User` object into a `GuildMember` object using the [`Guild.member()` function](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member):

```js
message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
```

**However**, [`message.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) returns a collection of every *`GuildMember`* that was mentioned, eliminating the need to convert a `User` object to a `GuildMember` later in your code, as it would already be a `GuildMember`.

Comment: I don't really see the difference, can you explain to me ?

Comment: Definitely! I edited my answer with a more in-depth explanation, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually *mentions.user**s**.first()*.
See [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users).