# Cannot read property 'first' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a mute command for my discord bot and I'm getting the error:

`Cannot read property 'first' of undefined`

```js
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const MuteroleCommand = require('./MuteroleCommand');
const { muterole } = require('./MuteroleCommand.js')

module.exports = class MuteCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('mute', 'moderation', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You do not have Permission to use this command.");
    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("I do not have Permissions to mute members.");
    const Embedhelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Mute Command')
    .setColor('#6DCE75')
    .setDescription('Use this command to Mute a member so that they cannot chat in text channels nor speak in voice channels')
    .addFields(
      { name: '**Usage:**', value: '=mute (user) (time) (reason)'},
      { name: '**Example:**', value: '=mute @Michael stfu'},
      { name: '**Info**', value: 'In order for the command to work, a muterole must be provided. this can be done by "=muterole <role ID>"\nYou cannot mute yourself.\nYou cannot mute me.\nYou cannot mute members with a role higher than yours\nYou cannot mute members that have already been muted'}
   )
    .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());
    
    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.member.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    const banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('You have been Muted in '+message.guild.name)
     .setDescription('Reason for Mute: '+reason)
     .setColor('#6DCE75')
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

   if (!reason) reason = 'No reason provided';
   if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (!mentionedMember.bannable) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (mentionedMember.user.id == message.author.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (typeof muterole === undefined) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (mentionedMember.user.id == client.user.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (mentionedMember.roles.cache.has(muterole.id)) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= mentionedMember.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);

   await mentionedMember.send(banEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
   await mentionedMember.roles.add(muterole.id).catch(err => console.log(err).then(message.channel.send('There was an error while muting the member')))

  } 
}
```

I'm not sure why this error occurred and I'm also not sure if there are more errors in this code, I would very much like to know what the issue is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633156/typeerror-cannot-read-property-first-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```js
const mentionedMember = message.mentions.member.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
```

Your issue seems to be that `message.mentions.member` is undefined

The [MessageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) class does not contain a field called `member`, however it does have a field called `members` which I assume is what you're looking for.

Replace `member` with `members` and you should be good to go! :)

Comment: i did what @kess told me to do but now im getting a different error ```cannot read property 'id' of undefined```

Comment: yeah we are not a runtime executor, please provide more information like the line thats triggering the error

Answer (score 0):

acoording to [Discord js Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) it is message.mentions.member**s**.first() not `message.mentions.member.first()`